# Открытие файла из локальной сети

Tags: windows, cmd, сеть

Я из командной строки windows запускаю файл реестра так:

```
>regedit /s C:\file.reg
```

Как мне запустить этот файл если он находиться в локальной сети? например по адресу //comp/folder/file.reg или //172.31.200.200/folder/file.reg

или можно сделать bat файл, но чтобы также запускать его из командной строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При доступе к компьютеру в локальной сети используется `\\NAME_OR_IP` а не `//NAME_OR_IP`.

Команда выглядит вот так:

```
regedit /s \\COMP\Folder\file.reg
regedit /s \\172.31.200.200\Folder\file.reg
```

Comment: да я так тоже пробовал, не работает

Comment: В чем выражается неработоспособность? У меня команда выполняется. Как с параметром /s (silent, без вывода подтверждения), так и без.